# SPD 2010 Approval Workflow multiple approvers (based on condition)

Tags: workflow, approval

I'm working on building an Approval workflow in SPD 2010 for a resource calendar. I'm somewhat experienced in some areas on workflows but I'm running into issues on how to set it up. I apologize if there is already a thread for this.

Based on 1 specific field I want the current item to require approval from just only SP Group 1 if the field is 'negative.' If the field is 'positive' I want the item to require approval from SP Group 1 and SP Group 2 in serial.

What is the best way to go about putting this together?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: OOTB, no, you won't be able to do that. You'd have to resort to designer to dynamically pick your group to assign the task to.

Comment: I've edited my original post. How do I dynamically pick which (or both) groups if the condition of approval is based off of a field value?

Comment: What version of SharePoint

Comment: Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add multiple approval group with semicolon separated[image] and select one at time (serial), so once Approval will approve the request then mail will trigger to approves 2 and he can approve/reject. it works for me to achieve multiple level of approval workflow.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it isn't dynamically picking who it needs to go to, it blasts everyone.

Comment: By theory this would mean both groups are approving every item, correct? What I'm trying to achieve is that i need the current item to require approval from only one group if a 'yes/no' field item has a "no" value. If the field contains a "yes" value, I want the current item to require approval from Group 1 and Group 2 in serial.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. Create a workflow variable. Name it as, let's say, "Approver Name".
2. Before you start the approval workflow, insert a step before that. Use the If condition.
3. Within the If condition, assign the name/email of the person for condition "Yes" and vice versa for "No".
4. In the approval workflow, assign the workflow variable as the approver recipient.